# sethostname and proc/sys/kernel/hostname

Tags: embedded-linux, hostname

I saw two ways for configure hostname of linux embedded system
1. sethostname
2. /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
I found sethostname ,but found it not helpful too much
are they basically same(sethostname wraps kernel/hostname file) thing or any difference??

Answer (score 0):

They are both equivalent.

From `procfs(5)`:

> **`/proc/sys/kernel/domainname` and `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`**
>
> can be used to set the NIS/YP domainname and the hostname of your box in exactly the same way as the  commands  `domainname(1)` and `hostname(1)`, that is:
>
> ```
> # echo 'darkstar' > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
> # echo 'mydomain' > /proc/sys/kernel/domainname
> ```
>
> has the same effect as
>
> ```
> # hostname 'darkstar'
> # domainname 'mydomain'
> ```

And from `hostname(1)`, it uses `sethostname(2)`:

> **SET NAME**
>
> When called with one argument or with the `--file` option, the commands set the host name or the NIS/YP domain name. `hostname` uses the `sethostname(2)` function, while all of the three `domainname`, `ypdomainname` and `nisdomainname` use `setdomainname(2)`.

The only difference is that `sethostname(2)` doesn't need `/proc` mounted to work.